# Tomcat 7 many Exceptions

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, web

I have a problem with my Tomcat 7. When I try to launch the application via Eclipse, Tomcat throws exceptions. App is very simple, it is "Hello World".

```
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:441)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<clinit>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:109)
    ... 17 more

Sep 23, 2012 8:14:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:441)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<clinit>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:109)
    ... 17 more

Sep 23, 2012 8:14:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 23, 2012 8:14:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/MVC_TEST] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 23, 2012 8:14:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 23, 2012 8:14:52 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Sep 23 20:14:52 CEST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 23, 2012 8:14:52 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
WARNING: Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Sep 23 20:14:52 CEST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:993)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4831)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Sep 23, 2012 8:14:52 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
WARNING: Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Sep 23 20:14:52 CEST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:350)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:993)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4831)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Sep 23, 2012 8:14:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:993)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4831)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Sep 23, 2012 8:14:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
```

In Tomcat classpath I have included:

> servlet-api.jar org.springframework.web.* org.springframework.orm.*
>   org.springframework.context.* org.springframework.beans.*
>
> And in user entries bootstrap.jar tools.jar tomcat-jul.jar

What is wrong?

Comment: Look at your application configuration may be it's wrong.

Comment: Do you think about `web.xml`?

Comment: Everything is possible, but I guess that spring.

Comment: I use Spring 3.1.2. In turtorial is version 3.0.5. It may cause bugs?

Comment: I don't think that a bug but version incompatibility possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/) you have shown uses maven. In that case the error is that you have to add the maven dependencies to the deployment assembly in eclipse.

```
Right click on your project -> properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Java Build Path Entries -> Maven dependencies -> Finish.
```

This should fix it.

Comment: I do this but in Advance field I see `Cannot find entry: "/home/user/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"` for all entry.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Spring, the errors are caused by a problem starting the Spring application context. Typically, you only have to look at the first errors: the other errors are cause by this one.

In your case, the application context fails to initialize because of the following exception. This means the Spring application context cannot be initialized at all.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<clinit>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:109)
```

Check that your web.xml file points to the correct Spring configuration files. If you are unsure, please post the relevant part of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added all the necessary jars, problem could be in web.xml. Do you have ContextLoaderListener in there ? In another way, you could have added XML namespaces to spring context which are not needed for "HelloWorld". If you need more help, please add SpringConfig file and your web.xml

Comment: All my file are identical to: http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/